# Type inference on nested generic functions

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference, lambda, func

I've searched a bit about type inference, but I can't seem to apply any of the solutions to my particular problem.

I'm doing a lot of work with building and passing around functions. This seems to me like it should be able to infer the int type. The only thing I can think of is that the lambda return type isn't checked by the type inference algorithm. I have stripped unnecessary logic to show the issue more clearly.

```
Func<T> Test<T>(Func<Func<T>> func)
{
    return func();
}
```

this compiles:

```
Func<int> x = Test<int>(() =>
    {
        int i = 0;
        return () => i;
    });
```

but this gives the error "The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly":

```
Func<int> x = Test(() =>
    {
        int i = 0;
        return () => i;
    });
```

I guess I would just like to know why it works this way and any workarounds.

Comment: very similar question, but not quite the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090159/inferring-generic-types-with-functional-composition

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say that the correct answer to the question is given by E.Lippert in [SO Why can't an anonymous method be assigned to var?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965576/why-cant-an-anonymous-method-be-assigned-to-var)

But let us play with your example a little:

```
Func<Func<int>> f = () =>
{
    int i = 0;
    return () => i;
};

Func<int> x = Test(f); //it compiles OK
```

No problem in type inference with your `Func<T> Test<T>(Func<Func<T>> func)` here.
The problem is hidden in that you use an anonymous lambda expression, the type of which cannot be inferred. Try this:

```
var f = () =>
{
    int i = 0;
    return () => i;
};
```

It gives [Compiler Error CS0815](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384140%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), saying

> Cannot assign lambda expression to an implicitly-typed local variable

and the explanation is:

> An expression that is used as the initializer for an implicitly typed
>   variable must have a type. Because anonymous function expressions,
>   method group expressions, and the null literal expression do not have
>   a type, they are not appropriate initializers. An implicitly typed
>   variable cannot be initialized with a null value in its declaration,
>   although it can later be assigned a value of null.

Now let's try another thing:

```
var x = Test(() =>
{
    Func<int> f = () => 0;
    return f;
});
```

It compiles as well. So the problem with your original example was actually with this line:

```
return () => i;
```

We can go further and according to what Eric Lippert says in his answer provide another function to wrap this:

```
static Func<T> GetFunc<T>(Func<T> f) { return f; }
```

Now we can rewrite your code like:

```
var x = Test(() =>
{
    int i = 0;
    return GetFunc(() => i);
});
```

And it works as well.

However, as far as I understand, this all is an overhead and you should just provide an explicit type. While these workarounds are suitable, when you need to have a lambda, returning an object of anonymous type.