# CS0411 The type arguments for method xyz cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, type-inference

So I'm a newbie, i was trying few things out, and I can't understand why the type can't be infered from the Test method, but can be infered from lambda expression.

```
class Program
{
    public delegate T2 DelegateTest<T1, T2>(T1 t1, T2 t2);

    public static T2 GenericMethodPlusDelegate<T1, T2>(DelegateTest<T1, T2> del)
    {
        return default;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GenericMethodPlusDelegate(Test); //type cannot be infered, won't compile
        GenericMethodPlusDelegate((int x, char y) => y); //compiles
    }

   public static char Test(int x, char y)
    {
        return y;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [type argument from Action<T> cannot be inferred, but from Func<T> can be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669968/type-argument-from-actiont-cannot-be-inferred-but-from-funct-can-be)